# How do I cut an angled cut with low clearance?

Tags: repair, wood, tools

I need to cut a header down on an angle to match my stairs. It needs to be cut on a 51° angle, which my circular saw can handle, but there isn't enough clearance under the joists to get my saw in there.
[image: header from the front]
[image: header from the end]

What kind of tool should I use to cut this? I have marked lines on the front and back, and I'm considering using a reciprocating saw and just trying to hold it steady. Is there a better way?

Easiest would have been to cut it before placing, but I really had to whack that thing to get it in and regardless it's in place now.

### Update:

I just used a hand plane and started going to town. It worked surprisingly well.
[image: planed header]

Comment: How important is it that the angle matches? You could just cut it close with the reciprocating saw, then put another piece in perpendicular to the angle if you need a flush surface to screw into.

Comment: That's a good idea. I need it to be flush with the stair stringers so the drywall will fit easily. I can add blocking to screw into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get a rough cut with a Recopicating saw, you can use a handheld power planer to finish the cut and get the right angle.  Just attach a scrap piece, cut at the correct angle, to the planer fence.

Comment: I really like this idea. I'm unsure how I would attach wood to the planer fence. I just can't picture how that would work.

Comment: I thought power hand planer, too. I'd skip the recipro saw, though, and just plane it from the start. By practicing a bit with the planer, and keeping a stable, consistent body position, you'll get a clean result without an angle jig, using the stair stringer as a guide. When I have to plane a substantial depth I alternate directions--the start and the finish often result in different cut depths for various reasons.

Comment: So I ended up just using a hand planer to do the whole thing. It worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[planer fence 1[image: ][1]]You will have to get creative with the fence.  I have added a few pics to help.  You will want to use a much shorter piece to ride along the flat part of the header and you will have a little part on the ends that will need to be finished by hand.  The pics were done very quickly and are just to give you the idea.[image]

Answer (score 1):

A handsaw will do the job and is the cheapest tool that will if you need to buy something for this. A sharp ripsaw would be best - the coarser side of the low-end pull saws is probably the easiest way to find one of those in the current market.

[image: image from Stanley - double-sided pull saw]